# set back counter to 0 if nothing is checked Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple dropdowns that contain checkboxes and my goal is "on click" to check how many boxes are checked and if it's more than 1 to hide a logo.

I have 2 Problems.

**Problem 1:**

The counter never sets to 0 if no check box is checked.

**Problem 2:**

Every time I click it runs through the function multiple times and I end up getting multiple console.logs which is bad and confusing.

```js
function init() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-multi-select-list-item");

        var myFunction = function () {
            var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
                count = 0;
            for (var ii = 0; ii < inputElems.length; ii++) {
                if (inputElems[ii].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[ii].checked === true) {
                    count++;
                    console.log(count);
                    if (count === 1){
                        console.log("show logo");
                    }else{
                        console.log("hide logo");
                    }
                }
            }}

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
        }
    }
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
   <div class="filter-multi-select-dropdown filter-panel-item-dropdown collapse show" id="filter-manufacturer-707419086" style="">
    <ul class="filter-multi-select-list">
        <li class="filter-multi-select-list-item">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-multi-select-checkbox" data-label="Dockers by Gerli" value="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546" id="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546">
                <label class="filter-multi-select-item-label custom-control-label" for="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546">Dockers by Gerli</label>
            </div>
        </li> 
        <li class="filter-multi-select-list-item">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-multi-select-checkbox" data-   label="Nike" value="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236" id="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236">
                <label class="filter-multi-select-item-label custom-control-label" for="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236">Nike</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any solution to the mentioned problems that I have is appreciated.

Comment: You execute the `console.log` only if one checkbox is selected. The fact that you're not logging `count` doesn't mean that it's not set to 0

Comment: Try using a debugger and everything will be clear

Comment: Problem 2 - you have your console.logs inside a loop, so you're going to get multiples.

Comment: @James oh so that why when more than 1 checkbox is checked it runs through it for each checkbox that is checked , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the nodelist to get only the `<input>`'s that are checked.

Then we can simplify the condition to:

- Hide logo the amount of checked `<input>`'s **is not** `1`:

```js
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var checked = [ ...inputElems ].filter(e => e.checked).length;
var hideLogo = checked !== 1;
console.log('Should hide logo: ', hideLogo);
```

---

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-multi-select-list-item");

var myFunction = function () {
    var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var checked = [ ...inputElems ].filter(e => e.checked).length;
    var hideLogo = checked === 0 || checked > 1;
    console.log('Should hide logo: ', hideLogo);
}

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-multi-select-dropdown filter-panel-item-dropdown collapse show" id="filter-manufacturer-707419086" style="">
<ul class="filter-multi-select-list">
    <li class="filter-multi-select-list-item">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-multi-select-checkbox" data-label="Dockers by Gerli" value="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546" id="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546">
            <label class="filter-multi-select-item-label custom-control-label" for="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546">Dockers by Gerli</label>
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li class="filter-multi-select-list-item">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-multi-select-checkbox" data-   label="Nike" value="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236" id="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236">
            <label class="filter-multi-select-item-label custom-control-label" for="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236">Nike</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, while running the snippet i realized when unchecking all boxes it still says hide logo : false, it should be true. can u help with that change ?

Comment: Why should it return true? you said: "and if it's more than 1 to hide a logo". If you uncheck everything, it should show the logo right?

Comment: basically if more than one checked or all unchecked  i dont want to show logo

Comment: Ahhh, clear now. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `count` globally and only listen to the element you clicked. You don't need to go through all the elements to check the count again

The count will be updated according to every click on 1 element

```js
function init() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-multi-select-list-item");
  var count = 0;
  var myFunction = function(event) {
    //only check the current clicked checkbox
    if (event.target.checked) {
      count++; //if it's ticked, we increase the count
    } else {
      count--; //if it's unticked, we decrease the count
    }
    console.log(count);
    if (count === 1) {
      console.log("show logo");
    } else {
      console.log("hide logo");
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <div class="filter-multi-select-dropdown filter-panel-item-dropdown collapse show" id="filter-manufacturer-707419086" style="">
    <ul class="filter-multi-select-list">
      <li class="filter-multi-select-list-item">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-multi-select-checkbox" data-label="Dockers by Gerli" value="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546" id="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546">
          <label class="filter-multi-select-item-label custom-control-label" for="ba4fa0f5f0784bcfa485e359cbe92546">Dockers by Gerli</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="filter-multi-select-list-item">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input filter-multi-select-checkbox" data- label="Nike" value="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236" id="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236">
          <label class="filter-multi-select-item-label custom-control-label" for="d9e943a4c0c2419cbd87d5100d221236">Nike</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , works just how i wanted to :=)

Comment: @Zyfella You're welcome!~ the key change here is that you don't need to go through all elements. That will help to improve your code performance as well as logic a lot :D

Comment: You go back and forth for answers. That's weird tho :'( @Zyfella

Comment: Nick Vu both of your answers work, however he first answered so i thought i would be fair if i give him the solution check. yours will be upvoted and appreciated aswell, i just dont have enough reputation to upvote. Thank you very much

Comment: @Zyfella oh okie, that's fair tho :D. By the way, using `filter` is not good for your simple case, that will cause a small performance problem due to elements looping. Let's say if you have 1000 checkboxes, but you only want to check tick/untick on a single checkbox. With `filter`, it will go through all checkboxes, but with counter, you only simply check the count. Anyway, I respect your choice, but be aware of what you're using :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use a querySelectorAll which returned all checked checkboxes, and look at the length property.

```
var count = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```